# Visualising PAM clusters

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm using the PAM algorithm for clustering  and would like to visualize the results. `enter code here`

```
# Computing PAM Clustering

pam.res <- pam(WKA_ohneJB_sam, 4)

print(pam.res)

# Adding Point Classification

point_class <- cbind(WKA_ohneJB_sam, cluster = pam.res$cluster) 
head(point_class, n=20)

# Cluster Mediods

pam.res$medoids

# Visualizing PAM Clusters

fviz_cluster (pam.res, 
              palette = c("#00AFBB", "#FC4E07", "#2E9FDF", "#006600"), # color palette
              ellipse.type = "t",  #Concentration ellipse 
              repel = TRUE, # Avoid label overplotting (slow) 
              ggtheme = theme_classic() 
              )
>  
> Error : The dimension of the data < 2! No plot.
```

What exactly do I have to change in my Syntax?

[image]

Comment: can you do dput(head(WKA_ohneJB_sam,20)) if the data is not too being? Because I tried it on iris and it's no problem

Comment: Like this  fviz_cluster(pam(iris[,1:4],4))

Comment: @StupidWolf I have attached part of the Output.

Comment: sorry dude i cannot do anything with an image. can you do as i suggested above, or you have some way of sharing the data, e.g github